# Form being sent with empty fields while validation and captcha are present

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, spam

I have a form that opens in colorbox, validates on submit, and utilizes reCatpcha to reduce spam. Even with all of these measures in place the form seems be getting sent with completely empty fields.

I have no idea how this is happening as I have no clue how someone (bot or human) is able to bypass everything and then submit the form with empty fields.

I realize this is a fairly specific issue, so I've tried to ask the question in a way that could benefit others as well. The validation is all done through Javascript, so perhaps a bot without javascript is able to bypass the validation. That being said, I find it odd the form is sent with completely empty fields every time this happens.

Hopefully someone can provide some generally thoughtful ideas as to how the form is getting submitted. If others have ever experienced this before, I'm sure some suggestions as to where to look could really help everyone out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If all of your validation is JavaScript, then it is quite possible for the form to be submitted by a bot, and there's no reason the bot would put anything in any of the fields.

Another thought, do you have any cross-site prevention measures? Could the form submission be originating off-site?